# WordPress - A submission confirmation on modal pop up

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, modal-dialog

I am trying to get a popup submit button working but I haven't quite found the solution I'm looking for.

I am using the [jquery modal](http://jquerymodal.com/) plugin to show the client the content of their changes before they submit them. However, when I try submitting, nothing happens. The submit button exists on the pop up, whereas the .modify button is the button that opens it. I am having no issues with the pop up itself.

My console test is printing so I know there's nothing wrong with my event listener. Maybe it has something to do with event.preventDefault()?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

Back end

```
   jQuery(".modify").click(function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var submit = confirm('Are you sure?');
                        <?php
                            $post_ids = array();
                            while($author_entry_posts->have_posts()) : $author_entry_posts->the_post(); 

                        array_push($post_ids, get_the_ID());

                        endwhile;
                        ?>

                        if (submit == true) {
                            var data = {
                                'action': 'modalcall',
                                'postid': <?php echo  json_encode($post_ids)?>,
                                'userid': <?php echo get_current_user_id() ?>
                            };
                            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                                 jQuery(response).appendTo('body').modal();

                                  //Script which handles the submit button on the modal pop-up
                                 jQuery(".modal_submit").click(function() {
                                     console.log("test");
                                    jQuery().submit();    
                                });
                            });

                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Front end

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button modal_submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handler for click on modal submit you are not defining which form needs to be submitted.

```
jQuery(".modal_submit").click(function() {
   console.log("test");
   jQuery().submit(); // you are not defining which form to submit.
});
```

Instead the `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button modal_submit">` needs to be inside a form which needs to be submitted by calling jquery submit on it.

```
jQuery(".modal_submit").click(function() {
   console.log("test");
   $(this).closest('form').submit(); // asking to submit the form which contains this button
});
```

Comment: I should of realised this. Thank you very for your help.